# Объект не создаётся внутри функции

Tags: python, ооп

Объект не создаётся внутри функции

```
class warrior():
    damage = 50
    helth = 100      
def test():
    print("da")
def tranning(colvo = 1):
    for i in range(colvo):
        command = "war" + str(i) + " = warrior"
        exec(command)
command = "war" + str(0) + " = warrior"
exec(command)
```

Comment: 1. Использовать exec очень плохая идея ) 2. Инициализировать поля классов принято делать в конструкторе, метод `__init__` 3. Поменяйте на `" = warrior()"` чтобы был объект был создан

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, для создания объекта нужно использовать не просто имя класса, а имя класса со скобками, вот так: `warrior()`

Во-вторых, никогда не используйте `exec`, если только вас не заставляют сделать это под дулом пистолета.

Генерить имена переменных в цикле - плохая практика. Если хотите создать много однотипных объектов, складывайте их в список или словарь.

`damage` и `health`, очевидно, должны быть свои у каждого объекта. Поэтому  объявлять их нужно в инициализаторе.

В итоге, ваш код будет иметь такой вид:

```
class warrior():

  def __init__(self):
    self.damage = 50
    self.helth = 100


def tranning(colvo = 1):
  res = []
  for i in range(colvo):
      res.append(warrior())
  return res

all_warriors = tranning()
```

Или короче с использованием comprehensive:

```
class warrior():

  def __init__(self):
    self.damage = 50
    self.helth = 100

def tranning(colvo=1):
  return [warrior() for _ in range(colvo)]

all_warriors = tranning()
```

Comment: Словарь с ключами `0,1,2,...` выглядит забавно. Проще (имхо) список использовать.

Comment: @andy.37, согласен, отредактировал ответ.

Comment: @andy.37 весьма спорно. Если мы изменяем словарь, и хотим чтобы ключи сохранились то список не подходит.